# How to close the Modal Dialog when state changed in React-Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Basically, I want to change the UI state in the Component when the Global state has been changed in the Redux-Store.

My scenario is as follow:

1. Show the Modal Form when a user clicks a "Add Student" button
2. Show "Saving..." when user clicks "Save" button
3. If an error occurs, the dialog should stay open and show Error
4. If insertion is ok, the dialog should be closed automatically

[image]

I have achieved the first 3 points, but I'm stuck at the 4th point and don't know how to implement the `Close` feature after the successful insertion.

I would like to run the following example code whenever isSubmitting/error has been changed in the Redux-Store.  But, I don't know where to run it.  I tried to put it in the render() method, but it doesn't work and I couldn't open the dialog anymore.

*Code to Check and Close the Modal*

```
if (isSubmitting === false && error === null)
     this.setState({ add: false });
```

I don't want to lift that UI state (Eg. IsModalOpen - bool) into the Global Redux store.  I have already put the UI state 'isSubmitting' into Redux and I don't want to keep adding UI states into the Redux Store.

Could you please suggest me how I can close the dialog after the successful insertion?

I put the sample code on the CodeSandbox and it's [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xlk549rm4)

**Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
      isSubmitting: false,
      error: null,
      student: null
    };

function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "STUDENT_ADD_BEGIN": {
      return {
        ...state,
        isSubmitting: true
      };
    }
    case "STUDENT_ADD_SUCCESS": {
      return {
        ...state,
        student: action.payload,
        error: null,
        isSubmitting: false
      };
    }
    case "STUDENT_ADD_ERROR": {
      return {
        ...state,
        isSubmitting: false,
        error: action.error,
        student: null
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default rootReducer;
```

**Container/Page**

```
class addStudentPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataList: [],
      add: false,
      edit: false,
      dataItem: {}
    };
  }

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      id: "",
      name: "TTCG"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      dataItem: this.getInitialState()
    });
  }

  toggleAdd = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      add: !prevState.add
    }));
  };

  showAddNew = () => {
    this.toggleAdd();

    this.setState({
      dataItem: this.getInitialState()
    });
  };

  updateItemState = event => {
    const field = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    let item = this.state.dataItem;

    item[field] = value;

    return this.setState({ dataItem: item });
  };

  handleAddNew = () => {
    let item = this.state.dataItem;
    item["id"] = uuid.v4();
    console.info(item);
    this.props.addStudentAction(item);
  };

  render() {
    const { isSubmitting, error } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Students</h1>
        <Button onClick={this.showAddNew} color="link">
          Add New Student
        </Button>
        {this.state.add && (
          <AddStudent
            toggle={this.toggleAdd}
            modal={this.state.add}
            item={this.state.dataItem}
            onChange={this.updateItemState}
            onAddNew={this.handleAddNew}
            isSubmitting={isSubmitting}
            error={error}
          />
        )}
        {this.props.student && (
          <h6>You have added a new student named: {this.props.student.name}</h6>
        )}
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    isSubmitting: state.studentReducer.isSubmitting,
    error: state.studentReducer.error,
    student: state.studentReducer.student
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  addStudentAction: item => addStudentAction(item)
};
```

**Modal Form**

```
export default class StudentAdd extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      modal,
      toggle,
      item,
      onChange,
      onAddNew,
      isSubmitting,
      error
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} centered>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Add New Student</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          {error && <Alert color="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form>
            <FormGroup>
              <Label for="Name">Name</Label>
              <Input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="Name"
                value={item.name}
                onChange={onChange}
              />{" "}
              type 'error' to simulate error
            </FormGroup>
          </Form>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={onAddNew} disabled={isSubmitting}>
            {isSubmitting ? "Saving..." : "Save"}
          </Button>{" "}
          <Button color="secondary" onClick={toggle}>
            Cancel
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATES**

It can be achieved by using `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method as below:  please be careful that you check the props and states correctly before deriving the state.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { isSubmitting, error } = this.props;
    if (isSubmitting !== prevProps.isSubmitting || error !== prevProps.error) {
      if (isSubmitting === false && error === null)
        this.setState({ add: false });
    }
  }
```

Or you can use `getDerivedStateFromProps` lifecycle method to re-calculate the props.  But I found it difficult to use than `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

It is bit more complex and clumsy to achieve that, but you can still force that behavior as follow:

Using `Promise` on your action:

```
export const addStudentAction = item => {
    return function(dispatch) {
        dispatch({ type: 'STUDENT_ADD_BEGIN' });

        setTimeout(() => {
            if (item.name !== 'error') {
                // HERE
                Promise.resolve(
                    dispatch({ type: 'STUDENT_ADD_SUCCESS', payload: item })
                );
                dispatch(closeModal('AddStudentModal'));
            } else {
                // HERE
                Promise.resolve(
                    dispatch({
                        type: 'STUDENT_ADD_ERROR',
                        error: 'Intentional Error Message'
                    })
                );
            }
        }, 1000);
    };
};
```

Will let you chain your `setState` and close the modal right after saving the item:

```
handleAddNew = () => {
    let item = this.state.dataItem;
    item['id'] = uuid.v4();
    this.props.dispatch(addStudentAction(item)).then(() => {
        console.log('boom');
        this.setState({ add: false });
    });
};
```

Note that in order to do so, you will need to use `dispatch` on your actions explicitly for each action, instead of using `mapDispatchToProps`.

I have modified the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mmyq1y62z9) so you can inspect the desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  However, it doesn't work.  This morning, I lifted the ui state onto Redux and accidentally overwrote the CodeSandbox.  That's why it's working when you tried.  I forked and rolled back my recent changes and applied as per your suggestion in this new CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/4xlk549rm4  You can notice that, it doesn't even trigger the dispatch.

Comment: Ok, then modify your reducer. If you want to control the modal from your reducer, you should switch isAddStudentModalOpen from true to false in modalReducer  as you did previously with this.props.add in your state. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mmyq1y62z9